# Swing components showing up on wrong JPanel in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am getting components that leak over onto the wrong JPanel in my JTabbedPane. Please see below:

https://i.gyazo.com/c41aa45b5782bbbbfb2be322db87b535.mp4

I have no idea why this is happening, I've never seen it before.

This is on launch and first forcus. If I switch Tabs it stops and doesn't happen again.

It seems like a painting problem originally but its on the completely wrong JPanel so I don't understand how its doing this.

```
public class RepoPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form RepoPanel
 */
public RepoPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    FLOWSLIST = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    STARTFLOWS = new javax.swing.JButton();
    DELETEFLOWS = new javax.swing.JButton();
    REFRESHFLOWS = new javax.swing.JButton();

    FLOWSLIST.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(FLOWSLIST);

    STARTFLOWS.setText("Start");

    DELETEFLOWS.setText("Delete");

    REFRESHFLOWS.setText("Refresh");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(STARTFLOWS)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(DELETEFLOWS)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(REFRESHFLOWS)
                                            .addGap(0, 675, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(STARTFLOWS)
                                    .addComponent(DELETEFLOWS)
                                    .addComponent(REFRESHFLOWS))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                            .addContainerGap())
    );
}// </editor-fold>


// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton DELETEFLOWS;
private javax.swing.JList<String> FLOWSLIST;
private javax.swing.JButton REFRESHFLOWS;
private javax.swing.JButton STARTFLOWS;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

```
public class RippleUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public GraphEditor editor;
private RepoPanel repoPanel = null;

/**
 * Creates new form TabbedUi
 */
public RippleUI() {
    repoPanel = new RepoPanel();
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    mxSwingConstants.SHADOW_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    mxConstants.W3C_SHADOWCOLOR = "#D3D3D3";

    editor = new GraphEditor();

    BACKPANEL = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    TABS = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    CONTROL_PANEL = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    JPanel EDITOR = editor.createFrame(new EditorMenuBar(editor));

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(CONTROL_PANEL);
    CONTROL_PANEL.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1020, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 556, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    TABS.addTab("Control Panel", CONTROL_PANEL);

    TABS.addTab("Repository", repoPanel);
    repoPanel.setVisible(true);

    TABS.addTab("Editor", EDITOR);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout BACKPANELLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(BACKPANEL);
    BACKPANEL.setLayout(BACKPANELLayout);
    BACKPANELLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            BACKPANELLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(TABS));
    BACKPANELLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            BACKPANELLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(TABS));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(BACKPANEL,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(BACKPANEL,
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code
    // (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default
     * look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to initialize LaF");
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RippleUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
public javax.swing.JPanel BACKPANEL;
public javax.swing.JPanel CONTROL_PANEL;
public javax.swing.JTabbedPane TABS;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: We’ll need to see a [mre] to help you.  Make a copy of your code, remove as much as as you can while still being able to reproduce the problem, and edit your question and add the code to it, so we can observe the problem for ourselves and investigate which lines of code are causing it.

Comment: I have added the code for the JFrame and the JPanel causing problems.

Comment: Be very careful modifying netbeans generated code - the IDE will replace these sections when it sees fit.  Instead, stop using the Netbeans form editor

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the default look and feel, so I would suggest that the issue is with the look and feel delegate you are using - which goes beyond the scope of SO's capabilities

Comment: It does it on any look and feel, I've never had trouble with Netbean's jpanel before. But I will try building on from scratch

Comment: Building my own JPanel does not produce this. *sigh* I hate swing layouts. Thanks for testing.

Comment: Did you figure it out Danny? The variable names you have are not consistent with standard java naming conventions and it makes reading the code tougher.

Comment: You might consider using SwingExplorer https://github.com/swingexplorer/swingexplorer to help debug swing issues. It seems like one of the layouts isnt being properly applied until you 'trigger' it by switching tabs.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this (after commenting out the GraphEditor, look-and-feel, mxSwingConstants, and mxConstants), but I am still trying to determine why it’s happening.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
repoPanel.setVisible(true);
```

It is a JTabbedPane’s job to decide which of its tab components is visible at any given time.  You are stepping on JTabbedPane by doing this yourself.

Note that all components other than windows are visible when they are created, so this line shouldn’t be necessary.

Remove that line, and things should work as expected.

Comment: *"are visible when they are created"* While the default visibility for non-window components is 'visible'. It would be more accurate to say they are visible when added to a window that is made visible (even then with caveats, e.g. possible not 'visible' in a card layout or tabbed pane). I do get what you're saying, but thought I should clarify for the sake of newbies.